# error while processing [TRUE ===FALSE]

Tags: if-statement, testing, jmeter, performance-testing

I have the following in debugSampler

```
isBooth=FALSE
```

I have if controller with condition:

```
${isBooth} ===FALSE
```

it producess exception:

```
2016/04/06 18:43:51 ERROR - jmeter.control.IfController: NL for hh: error while processing [TRUE ===FALSE]
 org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "TRUE" is not defined. (<cmd>#1)
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `"${isBooth}"==="FALSE"`.

As per [the Docs on If Controllers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller), it will default to javascript interpretation. I'm not a javascript expert, but I assume it's having trouble converting `Strings` (which is what JMeter variables are stored as) to `Booleans`.

Also note that this technique will work for any string, not just `TRUE` and `False`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `"${isBooth}"=="FALSE"` in if controller.

[image]

And for more information follow [Document](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller)